# Looping over column headers one sheet and finding exact matches on another sheet VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen several posts about finding exact matches in VBA but can't find what I'm looking for. I have two sheets in excel. Sheet 1 has two columns (A and B) and has multiple words in multiple rows separated by brackets. Sheet 2 has several rows in columns A to Z. I want to get each column header from sheet 2 and see if it appears anywhere in sheet 1, if it does then I do nothing to that column on sheet 2. If doesn't appear in sheet 1, I want to delete the entire column from sheet 2. The code I have so far is working but it's not case sensitive. I need it to be case sensitive.

```
Sub findWords()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim v As Variant, r As Range, rWhere As Range
    For i = 26 To 1 Step -1
        v = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i).Value

        Set rWhere = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B")

        Set r = rWhere.Find(what:=v, After:=rWhere(1))

        If r Is Nothing Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        Else
        'do nothing'
    End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Set r = rWhere.Find(what:=v, After:=rWhere(1), matchcase:=true, lookat:=xlwhole)
```

VBA .Find 'remembers' the last worksheet Find (ctrl+F) settings that were used by the user. It is best to be specific about as many parameters (i.e. options) that you can. More at [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel).

```
Sub findWords()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim v As Variant, r As Range, rWhere As Range

    Set rWhere = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B")

    For i = 26 To 1 Step -1
        v = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i).Value
        Set r = rWhere.Find(what:=v, After:=rWhere(1), matchcase:=true, lookat:=xlwhole)

        If r Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        Else
            'do nothing'
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```